# R: multi-index on columns and/or rows

Tags: r, dataframe

In `python`, and more specifically in `pandas`, I can work with `MultIndex` on rows or columns. Is there an equivalent in `R`? I was checking several tutorials, such as the one in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Working_with_data_frames, but I couldn't find a proper `R` equivalent.

As an example I have the following data frame:

```
   A-1  A-2 B-1 B-2
0  1    2    0   1
1  2    0    1   3
2  4    1    3   2
```

I want it to look like:

```
   A         B
   1    2    1   2
0  1    2    0   1
1  2    0    1   3
2  4    1    3   2
```

Other relevant answers I have found from stackoverflow

1. [Set columns as index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643166/set-a-data-frame-column-as-the-index-of-r-data-frame-object)
2. [Paste multiple columns to an index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344779/combining-first-two-columns-and-turn-it-into-row-names-in-r-data-frame)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560683/create-a-table-in-r-with-header-expanding-on-two-columns-using-xtable-or-any-pac

Comment: The power of `MultiIndex` is one of the reasons python/pandas is sometimes preferable to R for data manipulation.  `R` does not support the same type of hierarchical indexing.

Comment: @user227710 This looks  promising. does this `tables` package also allows you to do a multi-index on rows?

Comment: @tegancp hmm I see. I am mainly looking for some work around. personally I love the `MultiIndex` feature in `pandas`

Comment: R provides an array-class that might offer some of the features illustrated but doesn't have a print method that would immediately display as you demonstrated. There is an `ftable` function that allows "flattening" of higher dimensioned tables.

Comment: @tegancp R data.table does support multi key indexing.

Answer (score 9):

Given that you were looking for a "work around" I will give you an admittedly limited one. Arrays in R can only hold one mode (which contrary to most people's understanding can include lists)

```
>   arr1 <- matrix(scan(), 3,byrow=TRUE) 
1:   1    2    0   1
5:   2    0    1   3
9:   4    1    3   2
13: 
Read 12 items
> arr2 <- array(arr1, c(3,2,2))  # Re-dimensioning can also be done with `dim<-`
> arr2
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    0
[3,]    4    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    3    2

> dimnames(arr2) <- list( rows=0:2, subcat=1:2, majorcat=c("A","B") )
> arr2
, , majorcat = A

    subcat
rows 1 2
   0 1 2
   1 2 0
   2 4 1

, , majorcat = B

    subcat
rows 1 2
   0 0 1
   1 1 3
   2 3 2
```

After setting this up, there is a display method that delivers something like what you requested:

```
> ftable(arr2, row.vars=1)
     subcat   1   2  
     majorcat A B A B
rows                 
0             1 0 2 1
1             2 1 0 3
2             4 3 1 2
```

Looks like I needed to specify it differently :

```
> ftable(arr2, row.vars=1, col.vars=3:2)
     majorcat A   B  
     subcat   1 2 1 2
rows                 
0             1 2 0 1
1             2 0 1 3
2             4 1 3 2
```

Comment: great! I know i didn't mention this in the question but in order to export this to a csv/excel am guessing i need to do the following? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28640799/2423379

Comment: If it doesn't paste as you expect, Excel has a very neat fixed width import wizard.